# Difference between OOAD and UML?

Tags: uml, ooad

I am new to software field. I don't know difference between OOAD and UML. Can anyone suggest tutorials to learn about OOAD.

Answer (score 4):

OOAD is an idea of poem's author and UML is the set of words

- **Object Oriented Analysis & Design** is a way (set of principles, an idea) of making an application
  design.
- **Unified Modeling Language** is a notation which helps you to describe the design.

Comment: May agree with the answer, but OOAD = Object Oriented **Analysis** and Design. Indeed you can use it not only for Applications but for any kind of Software artifact in Software Engineering. See [**wiki**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_analysis_and_design)

Answer (score 0):

OOAD is Object Oriented Analysis and Design and UML is Unified Modeling Language. UML is nothing but a way to express your design which you will create using OOAD literature .

Answer (score -1):

I am very old in software industry and I tell you these things and fancy terminology is nothing so important . Remember Java is having now functional programming and JShell so you can understand why I am saying this . UML is useful in designing you classes , functions and data types with relationships but eventually it will change once you have implementations .

Eventually focus on design principles and your coding skills , theories related to too much of code design is not that useful .  Thanks

Comment: I thing my message went wrong . What I meant is too much of theories will not be beneficial w.r.t designs , learn design principles while you improve your code and apply the SOLID principles as much as possible . Thanks and sorry for my bad answers .